# How to get the placeholders in the text?

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable with a small text like:

```
$s = "bla bla bla {name} bla bla bla bla bla bla {city} bla bla bla {address}";
```

I need to use a regular expression to get ALL the name inside `{ }`

In this case I need an array as result with:

- "name"
- "city"
- "address"

How to use `preg_match` to get all the texts inside the brackets ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$s = "bla bla bla {name} bla bla bla bla bla bla {city} bla bla bla {address}";
preg_match_all("/\{([^\}]+)\}/i", $s, $matches);
$results = $matches[1];
```

Comment: why $matches[1] ? can I not get the names reading matches? at the moment print_r($matches) returns two array one with "{name}"... and one with "name"...

Comment: If no particular pattern order is set PHP will use [`PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) which: "Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern, and so on.". The groups you actually capture (those between brackets in the regex) will always be in `$matches[1]` it's just the way of it :-)